# template parameter incompatible with declaration

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a function that should generate a random integer or a random floating point value.
For that I want to use concepts.

Since integers and floating points need different distributions, namely `std::uniform_int_distribution` and `std::uniform_real_distribution` respectively, I use a separate struct  to select the correct type - also with a concept overload.
The "selector" looks like this:

```cpp
template<std::integral I>
struct distribution_selector {
    using type = std::uniform_int_distribution<I>;
};

template<std::floating_point F>
struct distribution_selector {
    using type = std::uniform_real_distribution<F>;
};
```

You see that I use `using` to have a different type selected, depending on whether I use an integer type or a floating point type.

Now my actual function:

```cpp
template<typename T = float, random_mode quality = random_mode::high_quality>
requires std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>
constexpr inline T rand(random& r, T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) {
    using distribution = distribution_selector<T>::type;
    if constexpr(quality == random_mode::low_quality) {
        return distribution<T>(min, max)(r.low_quality_engine);
    } else {
        return distribution<T>(min, max)(r.high_quality_engine);
    }
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/33fbzrYcY)

I receive the following errors (msvc):

```
Error (active)  E3244   template constraint not satisfied   Runtime C:\...\rand.h   35      type constraint failed for "float"
atomic constraint evaluates to false
          detected during instantiation of "T raid::rand(raid::random &r, T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) [with T=float, quality=raid::random_mode::low_quality]" at line 34
```

```
Error (active)  E0519   type "distribution" may not have a template argument list   Runtime C:\...\rand.h   37      detected during instantiation of "T raid::rand(raid::random &r, T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) [with T=float, quality=raid::random_mode::low_quality]" at line 34
```

What am I missing?

Comment: While errors because of templates can be a bit long-winded, please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete build log anyway. There might be hints in other parts of the messages.

Comment: I am not used to concept yet, but using an helper function (who use concept) seem help with this error (https://godbolt.org/z/GGM8rzsrv). Sadly there is still error

Comment: @MartinMorterol `distribution` is not a template, it's type is determined. https://godbolt.org/z/EETGsMv58

Comment: Thank you. Atleast it compiles! Is there a way to not use these helpers? :/

Comment: @Raildex Sure. Use the concepts in the specialization but not in the primary template https://godbolt.org/z/144qsxWf3

Comment: @Nimrod If you post an answer i will gladly upvote it

Comment: @Nimrod please make an answer :)

Comment: You can use std::conditional_t to enable to type in a single struct although it it messy. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dfKK9MvG7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the concepts in the specialization but not in the declaration of the primary template.
Also, `distribution` is not a template, its type is determined at its context.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct distribution_selector;

template<std::integral I>
struct distribution_selector<I> {
    using type = std::uniform_int_distribution<I>;
};

template<std::floating_point F>
struct distribution_selector<F> {
    using type = std::uniform_real_distribution<F>;
};

template<typename T = float, random_mode quality = random_mode::high_quality>
requires std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>
constexpr inline T rand(random& r, T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) {
    using distribution = distribution_selector<T>::type;
    if constexpr(quality == random_mode::low_quality) {
        return distribution(min, max)(r.low_quality_engine);
    } else {
        return distribution(min, max)(r.high_quality_engine);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/144qsxWf3)

Comment: thank you very much. Debugging templates is a bit hard. I did not notice `using distribution` *is* already a concrete type instantiation and thus does not need a typename at the constructor call.